# Select base elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

How can I select elements (using jQuery) that do not contain any elements?

For example, in the following tree:

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">
        <div class="c"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="d"></div>
    <div class="e">Lorem</div>
</div>
```

Only the `<div>`s with `class` `c`, `d`, and `e` will be selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(':not(:has(*))')...
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/GzNwe/3/)

If you want to do it with the `filter` function, be aware that `> element` will be deprecated in next jQuery versions!

you can use this:

```
$('*').filter(function(){
        return $('*', this).length == 0
    })
```

---

`:empty` selector won't work here because there is text node in the `<div class="e">`

<s>use `:empty` selector:</s>

```
$(':empty')...
```

[docs](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/):

> Description: Select all elements that have no children (including text nodes).

Comment: That's simple enough for me to understand.

Comment: p.s.: It says `[]` in your demo.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$('*').filter(function() {
    return $(this).children().length == 0;
});
```

You might also be able to use (faster) native DOM access inside the filter function:

```
return this.children.length == 0;
```

Comment: You just re-invented the wheel... :)

Comment: Isn't `$('> *', this).length == 0` return `true`?

Comment: @Derek: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: @Derek: it works http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eCfMf/, but personally, I'd use `$('div')` instead of `$('*')`

Comment: **Warning!** Your code is obsolete or deprecated. I'm checking the docs for the term... Found id: _"Note: The $("> elem", context) selector will be **deprecated** in a future release. Its usage is thus discouraged in lieu of using alternative selectors."_

Comment: Bleh, `$(this).children().length == 0`. I somehow doubt they'll make such a change in the 1.x branch though; that would break tons of scripts (for the same reason, attribute selectors still work without quotes)

Comment: @ThiefMaster. Check my answer with other version.

Comment: Hrm yeah, the `>` is indeed not necessary; no children implies no grandchildren :)